# using Polymorphic arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

i have a superclass `Dinosaur` with only one subclass `Tyrano`

i have `Dinosaur` with these attributes:

```
public Dinosaur(String name, String size, String movement, String diet, String terainType){
    ...
    //i've already made the setters and getters along with some helper functions
    }
```

and i have `Tyrano` with 2 additional attributes which are `teeth` and `hobby`

```
public Tyrano(String name, String size, String movement, String diet, String terainType, int teeth, String hobby){
    ...
    //made setters and getters with some helper functions
    }
```

now in my driver program i want to make an array type `Dinosaur` that will accept multiple subclasses of `Dinosaur` one of them which is the subclass `Tyrano` i don't know if its possible but my instructor said it is so here's what i did, this is on the main:

```
Dinosaur[] dinoList = new Dinosaur[9];
dinoList[0] = new Tyrano("Gary", "Large", "other dino Meat", "Land", 30, "singing");
int teeth = dinoList[0].getTeeth();
String hobby = dinoList[0].getHobby();
...//i also called the helper functions that were in Tyrano
```

it gets an error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
       dinoList[0].getTeeth();
                  ^
error: cannot find symbol
       dinoList[0].getHobby(); 
                  ^
...//along with same errors with the helper functions that were in Tyrano
...//it also happens when i call setters that were unique for the subclass Tyrano
```

and i don't know why it's doing this, i've double checked and i have no syntactical errors and i've already defined the helper functions, also those getters and setters, but there's no problem for the common ones which are found in the superclass `Dinosaur`

Answer (score 2):

If `getTeeth()` and `getHobby()` do not exist for `Dinosaur` class, you can't call them from a reference to a `Dinosaur`. Even if the actual instance stored in `dinoList[0]` is a `Tyrano`, you can't access its unique methods without casting the reference to a `Tyrano`.

This will work :

```
if (dinoList[0] instanceof Tyrano) {
    Tyrano t = (Tyrano) dinoList[0];
    int teeth = t.getTeeth();
    String hobby = t.getHobby();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the subclass from an array that contains its superclass, then you have access only to the methods that are available in the superclass, as these are the methods common among all subclasses.

```
public class Dinosaur
{
    private String hobby;

    public String getHobby() {
        return hobby;
    }
    ...
}

public class Tyrano extends Dinosaur
{
    private String teeth;

    public String getTeeth() {
        return teeth;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you have the following

```
 Dinosaur dinosaur = new Tyrano();
 String hobby = dinosaur.getHobby(); //this works
 String teeth = dinosaur.getTeeth(); //this is compile error!
 if(dinosaur instanceof Tyrano) {
     Tyrano tyrano = (Tyrano) dinosaur; //casting
     teeth = tyrano.getTeeth(); //this works
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical mistake. The point is, you have an array of Dinosaurs which don't have teeth or hobbies, is like if you have an array of Person and one of this "person" is a Teacher... not all the Person are Teacher like not all the Dinosaur have teeth.

So, you need to ask your Dinosaur "are you a Tyrano?" and if the answer is "yes" then... ask him "then, like a Tyrano, what is your hobbie?".

Let me put that in code:

```
//are you a Tyrano?
if(Tyrano.class.isAssignableFrom(dinoList[0].getClass())){
        // so, I treat you like a Tyrano
        Tyrano tyranoDyno= (Tyrano) dinoList[0];
        //tell me... teeth and hobbies please?
        int teeth = tyranoDyno.getTeeth();
        String hobby = tyranoDyno.getHobby();
}
```

Comment: Why the preference for `Tyrano.class.isAssignableFrom(dinoList[0].getClass())` instead of `dinoList[0] instanceof Tyrano`?

Comment: In the example is the same, just a personal preference. The main difference is that isAssignableFrom could chose a class in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a subclass, the subclass inherits the fields and methods from its superclass. So `Tyrano` has everything that `Dinosaur` has, and a bit more (`teeth` and `hobby`).

You could make another class, say `Stego`, which also extends `Dinosaur` and adds a field for `armour`.

Now your array of dinosaurs could contain both `Tyrano` and `Stego` types (they are both dinosaurs so this is fine). But your program has no way of predicting which type they will be. Since `Stego` has no `teeth` or `hobby`, and `Tyrano` has no `armour`, you can't use these fields directly (instead do as Eran suggested). You are however free to use all the fields from `Dinosaur`, since all dinosaurs are guaranteed to have inherited these